# Was American Airlines correct to refuse me boarding through Narita?

Tags: visas, japan, dual-nationality, american-airlines, stopovers

I am a Filipino-Canadian resident of Vancouver, Canada holding both Canadian & Philippine passports.  I was travelling from Vancouver to Manila the other day, with a one-way ticket purchased from FlightHub.

The ticket itinerary has a 21-hour layover at Dallas/Fort Worth, USA and a 17-hour layover at Narita, Japan. I left Vancouver on June 24th and stayed for the 21-hour layover at Dallas/Fort Worth, but when I checked-in for the forwarding flight on the morning of June 25th, American Airlines refused to check me in because they said I needed a visa for Narita, Japan before they could allow me to proceed with my travel.

I told them that being a Canadian citizen, I don't need a visa for Japan, and also being a Filipino citizen I don't need a visa for my final destination which is Manila, Philippines.

American Airlines was firm with their reasoning and refused me to continue with my travel and instead placed me on a flight back to Vancouver, Canada. Was the action of American Airlines correct? If not, what is my course of action to correct this wrong?  Could I get a refund of my ticket?

Comment: Were you carrying both Canadian & Filipino passports at the time?

Comment: Probably a bad case of “the system does not allow it” (as in, the system only allows a single passport to be entered and that one is used as the basis for required paperwork) rather than “regulations don’t allow it”. Where you doing through check-in, or just checking in to Tokyo? I suppose you escalated to a supervisor and/or a manager? Have you tried contacting AA customer service? You may want to check with a lawyer if they think you have a case.

Comment: It’s also surprising they sent you back. Wouldn’t they have been able to find another suitable (to them) routing?

Comment: Yeah, smells like a lazy check-in agent to me. I hope you escalated this at check-in.

Comment: Please clarify what documents you were carrying at the time.

Comment: @brhans I would go farther and ask whether Otrebor *showed* both passports to the airline.  If they did not see the Canadian passport then they would have been justified in treating the traveler as only a Philippines citizen.

Comment: I was carrying both Philippine and Canadian passports and showed both to AA staff & supervisor at DFW.  My flight originated from YVR, then had 21-hour layover at DFW, then supposed to proceed to NRT, and after 17-hour layover at NRT, to proceed to MNL.  But after the 21-hour layover at DFW, I was denied boarding for NRT and instead was re-routed back to YVR. The reason AA gave me was that I needed a visa for NRT, and I told them I don't need a visa for NRT because I have a Canadian passport, but AA still returned me to YVR.  Do I deserve a refund of my YVR - DFW - NRT - MNL air ticket?

Comment: @Otrebor please edit that information into your question, and then tag Jonathan in a comment and ask him if he'll re-open your question.